# Animating 5 views coordinated together

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation

I'm trying to create my own loadbar; It consists of 5 bars, sliding in from the bottom from the left to the right, then sliding out to the top in the same order. There should be a fixed amount of time (say, 0.2 seconds) between all of them sliding in.

Currently, i'm using a timer to start them one by one, and then let themselves repeat. However, if there's some lag during start or something, they get messed up. The first two or sometimes 3 bars go almost simultaneously, the gap is bigger, just name it and it happened. I currently just set fixed times when each animation should start, but some lag makes them go bogus.

Any given bar moves up in about 0.3 seconds, waits there for 0.2 seconds, then moves further up in 0.3 seconds. They start 0.2 second after their left neighbour, from left to right. Once they started, they just repeat it.

So, what could i use to coordinate them in such a way, that there will always be the same amount of time between them?

Other things i have considered was just using a lot of images (but that will need lots of images i suppose), or using Key Value Observing (KVO) to see when the previous bar is at the desired height.

Comment: It may help if you could develop and make available a small sample app that people can play with to help answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the NSTimer documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003747), NSTimer objects are not guaranteed to be realtime accurate on iOS.

> A timer is not a real-time mechanism; it fires only when one of the run loop modes to which the timer has been added is running and able to check if the timer’s firing time has passed. Because of the various input sources a typical run loop manages, the effective resolution of the time interval for a timer is limited to on the order of 50-100 milliseconds. If a timer’s firing time occurs during a long callout or while the run loop is in a mode that is not monitoring the timer, the timer does not fire until the next time the run loop checks the timer. Therefore, the actual time at which the timer fires potentially can be a significant period of time after the scheduled firing time.

It's an issue that effects NSTimer as well as OpenGL based games. [Michael Daley](http://71squared.com) mentions something similar in [his book](http://www.google.com/m/url?client=safari&ei=OnOLTdivLIrcNcP__-EB&hl=en&oe=UTF-8&q=http://www.amazon.com/Learning-Game-Programming-Hands-ebook/dp/B003ZUYIYQ&ved=0CB0QFjAB&usg=AFQjCNGoQHNPcTsrzLsijyogGYXYgh1onA) about how to set things up properly for an openGL based game. I suspect that this is suffering from the same similar situation.

That said, I would suggest preloading those images a adding them to the view just outside the bounds or frame of the visible view *before* you need then so that they are immediately available when you need them.

**Addendum:**

After thinking about this, I'm wondering if the C function `wait()` will help you here. It's a long shot, but perhaps it's worth a try. If not, then the answer may very well be that there is none.

**Addendum 2:**

I have no idea if this is going to help you either, but I found [this page](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part4/section-6.html), which discusses pausing a program for less than a second.

Comment: It's what i'm using, it's the coordination between the 5 that causes me trouble. I'll edit with some more info.

Comment: I know how to animate a view, and also: that method you're using there is deprecated. You should use block animations now.

Comment: Have you seen `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:`?

Comment: Yes, but the second has to start before the first one is finished. Say, each time one is about halfway done, the next should start. I might try using a 4 part animation: slide in halfways, slide in full, slide out halfways, slide out full, where at the end of a halfway it starts the next one.

Comment: So if you know approximately how long each animation takes, just time it appropriately.

Comment: I'll try to edit it to make it more clear, but thats what i did. The problem is that some lag makes them run out of sync; I timed them all nicely and when it loads smoothly they run perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information; However, this has not yet solved things i fear. The views are all loaded in the same cycle, and all the animations started in that same cycle too. Just the delay makes it lag. This is the very first thing being loaded, and after that all the other views get loaded and information gets pulled from the web. That's what causes the lag in the delay property, i suppose.

Comment: @ErikDolor - Yea, I'm afraid that the answer to your question is that there is no method to accurately time this. If you were dealing with seconds it might be more accurate. Millisecond accuracy won't be possible here.

Comment: Hm, bummer. Then i'll either have to use animationimages, or KVC, i suppose... just dont know which one is best :/

Comment: @ErikDolor - You can try the C `wait()` function, but I don't know if it can do milliseconds or if it's accurate either. Also, what do you mean by by KVC in this context?

Comment: Sorry, i meant KVO (key value observing), so checking when it is at a certain height and then starting the next one.

Comment: Ah, ok. You you can try that.